# How I can get the value (amplitude) at a given point by a HorizonInterpretation2D within a SeismicLine2D?

Tags: c#, ocean, petrel

The input parameters are a HorizonInterpretation2D and SeismicLine2D.
by selecting the horizon, petrel shows the value as shown in the image (red). To find this value from code I need to get the number of the sample (blue). How could obtain the number of the sample?

[image: Screenshot.]

ScreenShot Solution [[full size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDudl.png)]:

[image: Screenshot solution.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sample index on the seismic trace can be computed using the SeismicLine2D.FirstSampleAt and SeismicLine2D.SamplingRate, i.e. (pickedValue-FirstSampleAt)/SamplingeRate. Expect the seismic pick to be in between samples and plan for interpolation.

Comment: Thanks thomasG, I loaded an image with the solution, realized in version P2010.2. your comment was very helpful.